# Contour integral $|z-i|=1/9$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Calculate
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z^4+16}dz,
\end{equation*}
where $\Gamma :|z-i|=\frac{1}{9}$.
I have asked I similar question to this but I still do not understand.... when I find the roots of $z^4$+$16$ none of them are in the circle so is the answer just $0$?

I cannot find any similar questions to this to try to work from so I am very confused, please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if none of them are in the circle the answer is just $0$.

---

[Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)  says that if the function is holomorphic in the inside of $\Gamma$, and the inside is simply connected, then the integral is $0$.

THis is precisely your case.

The problem with curves that go around $0$ with functions like $\frac 1z$ is that the function is holomorphic in the circle *except* $0$ (a singularity!) which makes the region in which $\frac 1z$ is holomorphic not simply connected.

If you do not have singularities, though, the answer will always be $0$

Comment: really? is the answer that simple? I have been struggling with these questions for days because they're worth about 5 marks in exams and I didn't think the answer would be so simple.... so if none of the singularities (is that the right word?) are in the circle, the answer will always be zero?

Comment: This is the Cauchy's integral theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

Comment: @bws Yes. I added a little explanation but the basic point is that. :)